# How to enable AccurateECN on MacOS? (For testing L4S queue management)

Tags: mac, l4s, ecn

I'm trying to use *L4S queue management* feature in MacOS Sonoma. I've followed the online guides:

- [Reduce network delays with L4S](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10004/)
- [Testing and Debugging L4S in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/testing_and_debugging_l4s_in_your_app)

Basically I setup "Internet sharing" to allow traffic to pass through a Mac Mini using Linux devices as the endpoints. (This requires two ethernet ports so I use an USB Ethernet adapter as the second port).

The Linux client sends the TCP SYN with the correct flags enabled **ECE, CWR and AE**. However, at the **receive side**, **the same SYN** is received with only the flags **ECE, CWR**. This causes a fallback to classic ECN which means there's no L4S (TCP Prague) enabled.

It seems that, for some reason, the Mac Mini is modifying the TCP flags of the SYN message.

I did enable L4S as instructed by the guide:

```
defaults write -g network_enable_l4s -bool true
```

Anyone have an idea how to get the AccurateECN working on Mac?

#### Update: More details

The Linux devices are directly attached to the Ethernet ports on the Mac. There's no proxy or any other device between them.

The two Ethernet ports on the Mac are configured with a static IP and they have different subnets:

- Mac Ethernet Port 1 (built-in port): is configured with static IP 1.1.1.1/24 and itself (1.1.1.1) as the gateway
- Mac Ethernet Port 2 (USB adaptor): is configured with static IP 2.2.2.1/24 and itself (2.2.2.1) as the gateway
- The endpoints are configured as 1.1.1.2/24 and 2.2.2.2/24 respectively.
- (There's no internet access, so should be safe to use public IPs for this experiment.)

I capture using tcpdump on the Linux endpoints themselves and later open the captures with Wireshark.

- Client endpoint capture: I can see that the initial SYN is sent out correctly with 3 flags: AE, CWR and ECE.
- Server endpoint capture: I see the **same SYN** arriving with only 2 flags: ECE, CWR. (Note: this is the same SYN, not the SYN-ACK!)

My Wireshark is up-to-date and is able to recognize the AE flag and the Accurate ECN options in the TCP header.

Maybe the static IP config is somehow affecting the result? I'm willing to do more experiments if needed. Just let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Why are you using a mac for production work?

Comment: @Chopper3 There are not many test environments for L4S at the moment. This is one option that I'm evaluating.